# Why I can no longer can find FragmentDirection import in all my fragments?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

here is the screenshot of my problem

[image]

this import is previously valid, but I don't know why that FragmentDirections import is no longer valid, and it breaks my codes like below in that fragment. and this is occurred in ALL my fragments.

[image]

I don't know why they are suddenly become invalid import. please help. these are the lines I use in my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0-alpha04"
```

Answer (score 0):

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > "Invalidate and Restart" :/